# Borromean Lines of three $\mathbb{R}^1$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$ and analogous Milnor link invariants

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, gt.geometric-topology, homological-algebra, surgery-theory, knot-link

It is know that Borromean rings can be detected by Milnor invariant
$$
\bar{\mu}(\gamma_1,\gamma_2,\gamma_3)=
\# (\Sigma_1 \cap \Sigma_2 \cap \Sigma_3)-\frac{1}{2}\sum_{I,J,K}\epsilon_{IJK}
\sum_{\scriptsize\begin{array}{c}a\in \gamma_{I}\cap \Sigma_K \\ b\in
\gamma_{I}\cap \Sigma_J\\
x_a>x_b \end{array}}(-1)^{\epsilon(a)+\epsilon(b)}
$$
or
Milnor's triple linking number. See Refs:

- B. Mellor and P. Melvin, A geometric interpretation of milnor’s triple
  linking numbers,
  Algebraic & Geometric Topology 3 (2003) 557–568, [math/0110001].
- Braiding Statistics and Link Invariants of Bosonic/Fermionic
  Topological Quantum Matter in 2+1 and 3+1 dimensions
  Putrov,  Wang, Yau;  2016
  Annals Phys. 384 (2017) 254-287 (2017-09) DOI: 10.1016/j.aop.2017.06.019
  e-Print: https://arxiv.org/abs/1612.09298

[image]

From [1612.09298](https://arxiv.org/abs/1612.09298): It is easy to evaluate for the Borromean rings link. Consider realization of Borromean rings shown in Figure with
natural choice of Seifert surfaces $\Sigma_I$ lying in three pairwise
orthogonal planes. It is easy to see that the first term in
is $1$ while all other terms vanish. Terms are defined in [1612.09298](https://arxiv.org/abs/1612.09298).

> My question: The above well-known Milnor invariant is evaluated in $S^3$, and there are three $S^1$ circles. Can we define a link invariant, such that we have a set of Borromean lines (three of $R^1$) link in a infinite larger space $R^3$? (I think I can define the 3 lines along the $T^3$ via a surgery.) But I wish to have the following conditions satisfy:

- triple linking number defined in $R^3$.
- The three $R^1$ lines are extended in infinity in the space $R^3$.
- the three $R^1$ are linked in the similar manner as Borromean rings (or lines).

> Comments added: For instance, two $S^1$ circles in $R^3$ can form a Hopf link. One can stretch one $S^1$ into two parallel $R^1$ lines in $x$ direction. And we further stretch the other $S^1$ into two parallel $R^1$ lines in $y$ direction, where one of the $y$ line lies in between the two $x$ lines. These four $R^1$ lines form nontrivial linking, which we interpret as an infinite version of the Hopf link. Our question is whether there exists an infinite version of the Borromean ring.

Any Refs/comments are welcome!

> If the answer is negative, can we give a proof for impossibility?

Comment: I'm maybe missing something, but there are no obstructions that would limit three mutually nonintersecting, mutually non-parallel $\mathbb{R}^1$ lines from winding up in any configuration whatsoever, so there's no way of distinguishing 'linked' from 'unlinked' lines in a way that would be invariant even under linear transformations.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki Thanks! A comment is added in the end, which explains what we mean by $R^1$ lines forming a Hopf link. The question is then about an analogous version for Borromean ring.

Comment: Thank you - the comment is very helpful!  Note that just like in the Hopf case, you'll likely need to use two copies of $\mathbb{R}^1$ for each circle, so you may want to talk about six copies of $\mathbb{R}^1$, not three...